# Adding object methods implicitly

Tags: scala, object, implicit

Is there a way to implicitly add methods in scala object?

Upd: 
For example, Unfiltered scala library have singleton object `Body` which contains methods `Body.string(req: HttpRequest)` and `Body.bytes(req: HttpRequest)` for read body from http request. So, I want read body in my domain objects, like `Body.cars(req:HttpRequest)`.

Comment: Please explain better what you want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object ObjA

object ObjB {
  def x = 1
}

object Main {
    implicit def fromObjA(objA: ObjA.type) = ObjB

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println(ObjA.x)
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it... Is this the whole source file? Like ObjB.scala? Or is this part of some method implementation? I tried putting just this in my code and it didn't work...

Comment: @EduardoBezerra I updated the answer to work with 2.11.7, but I don't use Scala nowadays, so any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 11):

What do you mean by *implicitly adding methods*? Does this code snipper answer your question:

```
implicit def toFunkyString(s: String) = new {
  def reverseUpper = s.reverse.toUpperCase
}

"Foo".reverseUpper  //yields 'OOF'
toFunkyString("Foo").reverseUpper  //explicit invocation
```

Comment: `"Foo"` is a class instance, what I mean is adding methods in singleton object, something like `Math.myMethod(1)`. Is it all the same?