# Add method to companion object through implicits

Tags: java, scala, enums, implicit, language-interoperability

With typical classes, you can create an implicit class to add new methods to other class instances, just like this:

```
 implicit class IntWrapper(i: Int) {
    def otherMethod(s: String) = println(s"i: ${i} with ${s}")
  }
```

now you can do

```
3.otherMethod("something")
```

My questions are

1. <s>is it possible to add a method to the to the `Int` `companion object`?</s> (Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781153/4398050))
2. Imagine there's a Java `enum` defined out of your project, and you are using it in your Scala code. Java `enums` have the `.valueOf(s: String)` method that gets an enumeration value from a `String`, but that throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. I would like to add a method `.safeValueOf(s: String)` that would return an `Option`.

   Is it possible to do add that method to a Java `enum` in the same way we can do in the first example?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. A Java enum itself is not a value. So it cannot be converted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you *can* do for 2 (approximate, untested):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.util.Try

object SafeValueOf {
  def apply[E <: Enum[E]](s: String)(implicit tag: ClassTag[E]): Option[E] =
    Try(Enum.valueOf(tag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[E]], s)).toOption
}
```

Usage: `SafeValueOf[MyEnum]("something")`.